# How to configure IDE to run any node.js file from explorer?

Tags: node.js, testing, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, ide

I have a node.js project with some tests (it's my own test framework).

The structure of the project is the following:

```
app.js
tests
   - test1.js
   - test2.js
```

Inside the app.js file, I have a special setting that allows me to specify the path for running tests. If I run the following command from the terminal:

```
`node app.js`   all tests from the tests folder will be run
```

If I run the following command from the terminal :

```
`node app.js ./tests/test1.js` - only  the specific file will be run
```

I want to run these tests from IDE (I need to run all tests or the specific file) - from the Visual Studio Code or IntelliJ IDEA (by click on the file).

I've figured out how I can run all tests:

- for IntelliJ IDEA I set up Node.js configuration and now I can run tests by click on the app.js file:
  [image]
  [image]
- in Visual Studio Code, I can run all tests from the app.js file from IDE by clicking on Run command on the left panel
  [image]

My question is: how can I run the specific file by click on it from IDE (clicks on test1.js/test2.js)? I want to click on the file with the test and imitate the same command as I run it from the terminal:

```
node app.js tests/test1.js
```

I know that if I'd used some test framework like Mocha I've could use the special plugins, but using an external test framework is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that the best option for my task is would be to set up an NPM configuration for the project. The window for setting up the NPM configuration has some fields which should be filled:
package.json - path to your package.json
command - run
scripts - the name of the main script from the package.json file
environment - your environment variables (if you have it - they should be filled, because otherwise, the npm runner could not catch them from the '.env' file)

The most important field for my task is 'Arguments' -  I fill it with the path to file that I want to run and then in my node.js app I'm able to access it via the `proccess.argv` array.